# order_by not working on a filtered queryset

Tags: django

i have this view

```
    def post_list(request,user_id=None):          
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        
        if user_id:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')
        
        return render(request,'post/list.html',{'posts': posts})
```

the Order_by is working for Post.objects.all()

but not for Post.objects.filter(user=user) , any idea why?

they are rendered the same way, to the same html

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)


        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-created',)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"post by {self.user}"
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post:post_detail', args=[self.user.id,self.id])
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.post_list, name='home'),
path('<int:user_id>/', views.post_list, name='wall'),
```

and finally

```
  {% for post in posts %}
      <a  href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
        <h3>{{ post.user }}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    {%if post.text%}
    <div>
      <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
        <h3>{{ post.text }}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

print(posts.values()) on:

Non filtered queryset:

```
    <QuerySet [{'id': 19, 'user_id': 1,  'text': '333333333333333333333333333333',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)}, 
                {'id': 18, 'user_id': 1,  'text': '222222222222222222222222222222',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)}, 
                {'id': 17, 'user_id': 1,  'text': '11111111111111111111111111111',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)}]>
```

filtered queryset:

```
    <QuerySet [{'id': 17, 'user_id': 1,  'text': '11111111111111111111111111111',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)},       
                {'id': 18, 'user_id': 1, 'text': '222222222222222222222222222222',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)}, 
                {'id': 19, 'user_id': 1,  'text': '333333333333333333333333333333',  'created': datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)}]>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you sure the if block is being run? Can you share the `Post` model and the output you are getting?

Comment: @IainShelvington, yeah that is why it's bugging me crazy, once i filter the queryset the order stop working,else it is working just fine ,i just edited the post,

Comment: Strange... Can you give an example queryset result where the ordering is not being applied correctly? Result of 'print(posts.values())' would be good as it should contain the data

Comment: @IainShelvington, alright i just added the results of your suggestion to the post,

Comment: All three results have the same `created` value, the ordering is "working" as rows with the same value for the order key can be returned in any order. Do you want to order by `id` aswell? Perhaps changing `created` to a `DateTimeField` would give better results as it would also include the time

Comment: first off thank you @IainShelvington for you answers, but why is that i can change deliberatly change the order of the first quesryset (.all) .but not the filtered one , even though they have been made by the same user on the same view and template

Comment: I suspect that you might not be changing the order of the results at all since they all have the same `created` value. Adding the filter is probably changing the order in which your DB reads rows from the table which is why the two querysets return results in a different order. If you remove `order_by` do the results change?

Comment: ok. i will look into that, thank you very much

Comment: Changing to a `DateTimeField` will probably help you the most

Comment: yes, that totally worked, i was just looking at kind of time fields and filter, and your suggestion was so spot on ,thank you for your help

Comment: `order_by` works well, 2 results are different because 2 query SQL applied to the database are different (different about getting data). If you want to make sure that the result is the same, you should add one more field to order. Using DateTimeField instead DateField is a good idea but you need to refer to your database design first, no need -> don't change.